# How can I delete a particular file through the command line?

Tags: command, line

I'm using Ubuntu and would like to know if there is an easy way to delete a single file through the command line. In the same way you might use 'rmdir -r' to delete a whole file.

Comment: * correction, "in the same way you might use 'rmdir -r' to delete a whole folder".

Comment: Never mind I foud out... Feel really stupid for posting now... jusr 'rm "file name"'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `rm` command and pass the relative or absolute path as parameter, e.g.

```
$ rm your_file_name.txt
```

or

```
$ rm /home/craig/your_file_name.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the command `rm`.

More information can be found in the man-pages with `man rm`.